# How to customise tooltip text in amcharts4 piechart?

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I have created a  Pie chart using amcharts4,

```
  var total_sales=5000;

  let dchart = am4core.create("donutchart", am4charts.PieChart);

  dchart.data = [{year:'1996',sales:200},{year:'1997',sales:500},{year:'1998',sales:550}];


  let pieSeries = dchart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  pieSeries.dataFields.value = "sales";
  pieSeries.dataFields.category = "year";

  //tooltip
  pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = {value} {category};  /**this Line**/
```

Now on Tooltip I would like to display year,sales and total_sales as well.
 With this code, on tooltip I can obtain the year and sales from the value and category respectively. But What if I want to display the total_sales variable which is declared globally.How do i display it in the tooltipText?

Note:
I have tried changing the tooltip code to
`pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = {value} {category} {total_sales};`
But it wont work.Any ideas? Correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: So if `total_sales` is a global variable why not just add it to tooltipText as such? `pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = "{value} {category} " + total_sales;`

Comment: @martynasma i didnt know we could do that. Thanks a bunch!